# Is it necessary to have node.js installed to execute an electron app that is compiled to an .exe file?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to compile a node.js electron application to executables.
If I managed to do this, would the person who runs the app need node.js installed to run it?

Answer (score 5):

**No, the person would not need separate Node.js installed**.

> By embedding Chromium and Node.js into its binary, Electron allows you to maintain one JavaScript codebase and create cross-platform apps that work on Windows, macOS, and Linux — no native development experience required.

Source: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest